# std::map value is empty even though i assigned a value?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have a std::map like this :

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> imagePaths;
```

Later in my code I give it one value, like this :

```
imagePaths.insert(std::make_pair("Square.bmp", "Square"));
```

However, when I loop trough the map and display both first and second values like this :

```
for (auto iterator = imagePaths.begin(); iterator != imagePaths.end(); iterator++)
{
    std::cout << "Loaded > " << imagePaths[iterator->first] << " image path : " << imagePaths[iterator->second] << std::endl;
}
```

I get the output :

> Loaded > Square image path :

And the rest is, for some reason empty, even though I gave it a value of `"Square.bmp"`.

---

Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong way to display a map content.

Try this:

```
for (auto iterator = imagePaths.begin(); iterator != imagePaths.end(); iterator++)
{
   std::cout << "Loaded > " << iterator->first << " image path : " << iterator->second << std::endl;
}
```

To lookup a value using the key you use `.find()` method. In your case, if you execute this statement:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator i = imagePaths.find("Square.bmp");

std::string value = it->second;
```

value will be "Square".

Comment: This works, but what if I want to print out the value "Square"? I've tried this : `std::cout << imagePaths["Square"] << std::endl;` which didn't work.

Comment: I will in 2 mins, have to wait a bit before accepting. :P

Comment: Then you need to lookup a value ("Square" in your case) using the key ("Square.bmp"). So you use the .find() method. I added it in my answer.

Comment: Ohh, I managed to mix up the key with the value. I wanted to use "Square" as a key but I used Square.bmp as one instead :P Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The `std::map` maps the first element of the pair to the second, it does not work the other way round.

Aside from that, it does not make sense to apply the mapping in your loop at all because you already can access both values via the iterator.